# i create a two method one for take image from Gallery and other's take image from camera, but i face some codding Error, below is my code

Tags: flutter, dart

[image] I want to have capture images using camera and take image from gallery functionality in my android project and a tried to make them like below, below here is my two method for both of them, i thnik i have made some mistake, please help to fix??
1st Error A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File'.

```
    2nd Error, A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File'.

how to correct this error[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

i create   File _imageFile; in State Widget

```
     //Methods to Take images from camera,
         CaptureImageWithCamera()async {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                File  imagefile=await ImagePicker().getImage(
                    source: ImageSource.camera,
                        maxHeight: 680,
                        maxWidth: 970,
                );
                setState(() {
                  this._imageFile=imagefile;
                });
            
              }
        
        // here below is methoda to take images from gallery
        
         ImageFromGallery()async {
             Navigator.pop(context);
             PickedFile Imagefile=await ImagePicker().getImage(
               source: ImageSource.gallery,
             );
             setState(() {
               this._imageFile=Imagefile;
             });
        
          }
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        
        
          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBTx4.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from their very first tutorial:

```
Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Note how they are creating a `File` from the `pickedFile` because `pickedFile`is not a `File`:

```
_image = File(pickedFile.path);
```

You need to do the same.

And as a personal sidenote: why did you not read the tutorial? Given the time it took you to post this question and waiting for this answer, that would have been a lot faster. When you progress in programming, it will become more and more important to process this type of information, so start early.

Comment: i changes as you said but it still doesn't work, i get asynchronous suspension error

Comment: That does not tell me anything. Can you open a new question, with your updated code and a complete error message?